# xpages: Unable to configure inotes Calendar Control to use Resource Reservation DB

Tags: rest, xpages, lotus-domino

On Domino 901 fp10 hf66 I am trying to create an xPages showing the company resource reservation DB allowing filtering data for specific resource. I am facing a problem with restservice: it seems not able to retrieve all rows in calendar view.

```
<xe:restService id="restService2" pathInfo="/inoteslegacyjson">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:viewJsonLegacyService
            databaseName="${compositeData.databaseName}"
            viewName="${compositeData.viewName}" defaultColumns="false"
            var="entry" contentType="text/plain">
            <xp:this.columns>
                <!--  Cal Date --> 
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$134" columnName="StartDateTime">
                </xe:restViewColumn>
                <!--  Icon -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$149" columnName="$149"></xe:restViewColumn>
                <!--  Start Date -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$144" columnName="StartDateTime">
                </xe:restViewColumn>
                <!--  End Date -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$146" columnName="EndDateTime">
                </xe:restViewColumn>
                <!--  Description -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$147" columnName="Topic"></xe:restViewColumn>
                <!--  Alt Description -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$151" columnName="$151"></xe:restViewColumn>
                <!--  Type -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$152" columnName="$152"></xe:restViewColumn>
                <!--  Chair -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$153" columnName="$26"></xe:restViewColumn>
                <!--  Confidential -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$154" columnName="$154"></xe:restViewColumn>
                <!--  Status -->
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$160" columnName="$160"></xe:restViewColumn>
                <xe:restViewColumn name="$UserData"
                    columnName="$UserData">
                </xe:restViewColumn>
            </xp:this.columns>
            <xe:this.compact><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.CompactJson2=="true"}]]></xe:this.compact>
        </xe:viewJsonLegacyService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

The output json data strangely stops after position 10 of 13 siblings (view rows), the following is the last items.

The same view served by a xe:calendarJsonLegacyService run fine showing all 13 rows, so I do not think about a view-related problem.

Is there a way to debug a restservice?

{
          "@unid":"2BAACF5DA0620BC8C125826D002825FF",
          "@noteid":"942",
          **"@position":"10",**
          "@siblings":"13",
          "entrydata":
          [
            {
                "@columnnumber":"0",
                "@name":"$134",
                "datetime":
                {
                    "0":"20180413T140000"
                }
            },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the default count is 10.  Try setting the count:

```
<xe:viewJsonLegacyService
    count="200"
    databaseName="${compositeData.databaseName}"
    viewName="${compositeData.viewName}"
    defaultColumns="false"
    var="entry"
    contentType="text/plain">
```

The control `xe:calendarJsonLegacyService` does not have a `count` attribute.

Comment: @Francesco: if this answer solved your issue please accept the answer please https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/223607